# Is there a way to set a parameter from a stored procedure to a var query?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, validation

I'm working in a .net app specifically in a validation scripted in a stored procedure. This simple validation checks if there is already a policy with the same policy number that the user is trying to insert and throws an error message.

The problem that I'm facing is of the kind

> Procedure or function 'pr_Policy_CheckPolicyNumber' expects parameter '@companyID', which was not supplied.

That's because I added a new field from the same PolicyBill table named (CompanyID).

My question is if it's there a way to set the @CompanyID value directly to the function and fix that error

The stored procedure is

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_Policy_CheckPolicyNumber]
(
      @policyNumber VARCHAR(50) ,
      @effectiveOn DATETIME ,
      @companyID BIGINT

    )
AS 
    IF ( ( SELECT   COUNT(pb.policyBillID)
           FROM     PolicyBill pb
           WHERE    pb.policyNumber = @policyNumber
                    AND ( @effectiveOn >=  pb.effectiveOn ) and (@effectiveOn <= pb.expiresOn )
                    AND pb.isActive = 1
                    AND pb.statusID = 56
                    AND pb.documentTypeID = 1
                    AND pb.companyID = @companyID
         ) > 0 ) 
        BEGIN
            PRINT N'The Policy already exists';      
            SELECT  1
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SELECT  0
        END
```

and the Function is:

```
private bool CheckPolicyNumber()
        {
            var result = true;

            var query = $"EXEC pr_Policy_CheckPolicyNumber '{txtPolicyNumber.Text}','{deEffectiveON.Date:yyyy/MM/dd}', '@companyID'";
            var dt = AhkSqlHelper.ahkExecuteDataTable(query);

            result = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()));

            return result;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ***WARNING***: Your code is **dangerous**; it is wide open to injection attach. *Never* inject strings into your SQL statements, **parametrise** them. There have been countless examples of companies using such bad practices, and they have been named, shamed, and fined. There's also countless information on how to properly parametrise your statements. There is no excuse any more for ignorance of the fatal security flaw, nor how to properly write your code to deal with it.

Comment: Most likely, as well, if you parametrise your query properly, the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Ad mentioned in the comment, the original code is fairly dangerous and you could be open to SQL injection attacks. The best solution is parameterize your command, something like this should do the trick:

```cs
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

string connString = "YourConnectionString";
string spName = "pr_Policy_CheckPolicyNumber";

private bool CheckPolicyNumber(string policyNumber, DateTime effectiveOn, long companyID)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn))
        {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@policyNumber ", policyNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter1);

                SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("@effectiveOn  ", effectiveOn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

                SqlParameter parameter3 = new SqlParameter("@companyID ", companyID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter3);

                var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                return (bool)result;
        }
    }
}
```